# shell command: need help about a regex match

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I have a sentence that I want to write a shell command to grep it from a text:
The sentence is:

```
self.timeout=2.0
```

However, as this is a part of code from a file.
so it this sentence could also be

```
self.timeout = 2.0
```

or

```
self.timeout =2.0
```

or

```
self.timeout = 8.0
```

that is: there may be blanks besides "=", and the value of self.timeout maybe different.

So could anybody help to give me a regex in shell command.
Anyway, I know the shell:

```
grep "self.timeout*="
```

works.
But I think it is not a good regex in shell command.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do:

```
grep -E 'self\.timeout[ \t]*=[ \t]*[0-9.]+'
```

note:

```
      |      |          |  |           
  use egrep  |          | zero or more
             |    whitespace
             |
  make sure we're matching
     a dot instead of
      "any character"
```

Comment: slebetman, many thanks!
Yes, this regex works. Your regex is much formal than mine!
Thanks!

Comment: slebetman,many thanks for your detailed note. It makes me much better understand your regex. I found stackoverflow is really a good website!

Comment: +1 for the vertical lines.  Hard-work should always be rewarded ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep -E` aka `egrep` you can use a regular expression, with which the `*` operator will match 0 or more of the preceding character:

```
egrep 'self\.timeout *='
```

Or use `[[:space:]]` to match all whitespace characters:

```
egrep 'self\.timeout[[:space:]]*='
```

Comment: John, many thanks for your always quick answers.
The * operator will match 0 or more of the preceding character.
Yes, in fact, it is the answer I want!
I remember * can solve the problem, but I can't remember clearly.
Thanks a lot!
And many thanks for your second method!